# SSAS: How can I create calculated member using multiple conditions on different hierarchy

Tags: ssas, olap, member

I have problem with my SSAS Cube.
I have to implement basic calculation to my Cube:

### sum(Ammount) where BOOK = "Assets" and CD_PRODUCT_L4 <> "LoanLoss"

My dimmension is in image below:

Dimension attributes: BOOK, CD_PRODUCT_L4, CD_PRODUCT_L5, ..

Hierarchy PROD: CD_PRODUCT_L4 - CD_PRODUCT_L5

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Principal Loans] 
    AS (
        except(
            [PLV PRH HDIM CB].[BOOK].&[ASSETS_ON],
            [PLV PRH HDIM CB].[COD PRODUCT L4].&[51L4]
        ), 
        [Measures].[EOM PRINCIPAL_a])
```

The biggest thing is that conditions are not from same hierarchy level so I can't use except and I know no other way to implement this particular condition set

Please HELP, Thank you

[Product dimmension model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgc2w.jpg)

Comment: What does your MDX query look like? Have you attempted doing this prior to the consumption from SSIS?  My experience with BI/SSAS is that you get your Data Mart prior to consumption and Cube-ing.  I know certain components require processing during the Cube-ing process but it has made it easier for Aggregation if you have as many as you can possibly get done prior to the Cube process.

Comment: Problem is that I'm just cube developer here and staging is already deployed so moving logic to staging aread is no way to go unfortunately

Comment: DOH, What about your MDX aggregation query?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by MDX aggregation query, I need to add calculation member to my cube. I already try this: CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Principal Loans]
 AS (except([PLV PRH HDIM CB].[BOOK].&[ASSETS_ON],[PLV PRH HDIM CB].[COD PRODUCT L4].&[51L4]), [Measures].[EOM PRINCIPAL_a])

Comment: I am to assume that `51L4` is equivalent to "Loan Loss".  Thought about applying the conditions across both Hierarchies?  If the aggregation only applies to the `L4` Hierarchy, then have `L5` be 0 or NULL.  This will allow for future implementation's for `L5` conditions.

Comment: I'am not so good in theory, could you pls provide a example?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the issue by adding hierarchy to my dimension which allowed me to use except as I wanted before but I'am not satisfied with this solution because it looks more like workaround then solution

`CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Principal Loans] AS 
sum((except([PLV PRH HDIM CB].[Hierarchy BOOK].[BOOK].&[ASSETS_ON].children,[PLV PRH HDIM CB].[Hierarchy BOOK].[COD PRODUCT L4].&[51L4]),[Measures].[EOM PRINCIPAL_a]))`

Comment: Since you do not have access to the Warehouse/Mart, it seems to be your only solution.

Comment: It has to be another way to use multiple condition like this, I don't even dare imagine what will happen when there will be 3 and more condition like this

Comment: Let me review ours but it may be a data acquisition issue for fields.  I know we did a split for certain fields at the Warehouse/Mart level before the Cube and then the Cube did some minor aggregation's at the hierarchy.  More like a Case...When statement than yours.  Hold on....

Comment: Why are you aggregating an EOM value?  The Cube should be handling that part of the Calculation when joined with the Date Dimension.  Still reviewing our Setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the closest example that I can provide you to what you need.

This, code below, is just one of about 50 or so Measures we have defined, ranging from Counts, Averages, Sums, Percentages, etc.  We take a single DW value and perform at least 2 seperation calculations, most have 4 or more different calculations, from that one field.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Count Previous Difference]
    AS Case 
    // Test for current coordinate being on (All) member.
        When [Date].[YearMonth].CurrentMember.Level Is [Date].[YearMonth].[(All)]
            Then "NA"
        Else 
            ( [Date].[YearMonth].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Gross Count] ) 
                -
            (   ParallelPeriod (
                    [Date].[YearMonth].CurrentMember.Level,
                    1,
                    [Date].[YearMonth].CurrentMember
                ), 
                [Measures].[Gross Count]
            )
    End, 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Gross Count] }, 
VISIBLE = 0 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Some Summary';
```

Keep in mind we also use our DW & Cube with SharePoint and SSRS reports.